# Não é possível regenerar um client secret no Jasmin

Tags: api, oauth2, oauth

Ao aceder ao Nitrogen do Jasmin e actualizar um sistema de autorização do tipo Client Credentials não é possível regenerar o `client secret`. Actualmente dá um erro de que o respectivo `secret` não existe.

O facto da aplicação estar publicada tem alguma relevância nesta operação?

**[EDIT 2019/04/17]**

O erro que me aparece é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá João. Este problema já foi resolvido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema está a ser analisado, trata-se efetivamente de uma anomalia do produto.
Para contornar o mesmo poderá gerar um nova aplicação e *client secret*.

Se pretender manter o *application id* e gerar novo *client secret* pode entrar em contacto comigo através da PRIMAVERA (por questões de segurança).

Comment: Obrigado Jorge. Pedia apenas que assim que a anomalia do produto estivesse resolvida para mencionar neste post para efeitos de histórico caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Olá João sim podes fazer reset ao client secret, conforme podes ver na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio. O problema que me ocorre é exactamente quando uso essa opção. Actualizei o post original com a resposta do Nitrogen.